# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Self.Index'

Tags: swift

I want make an extension to Collection for fist item with this code:

```
extension Collection {
    var firstOneExist: Bool {
        if self.indices.contains(0) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error of `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Self.Index'` why I am getting this error? indices are Int so I used 0, the error tell me to use `as! Self.Index` but I do not see the reason for it.

Comment: A `Collection` does not necessarily have indices that are of type `Int`. For instance, `String` is a collection, but it's indices are not `Int`. If you want to add this to `Collection` then you should probably use `self.startIndex` rather than `0`. But you may also want to just add this to `Array` or something instead.

Comment: But also... your function seems odd. Collection already has a property `isEmpty` that will do exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: What do you mean by "firstOneExists"? Are you trying to check if the collection has at least 1 element? If so, you can simply use the `isEmpty` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could limit the computed property to only be available for collections whose indices are integers

```
extension Collection where Indices.Element == Int {
    var firstOneExist: Bool {
        self.indices.contains(0)
    }
}
```

Example

```
let values = [1,2,3,4]
print(values.firstOneExist) // true

let second = values.dropFirst()
print(second.firstOneExist) // false
```

Comment: I never realized that dropFirst() returned an ArraySlice. Your example really drives that home!

Comment: It also demonstrates that the fistOneExist computed var might have value.

Answer (score 0):

The index on a `Collection` is not defined as `Int`. It is an associated type called `Index`. It **may** be an `Int` but you can't just use an `Int` here.

FOr instance, `Dictionary` conforms to `Collection` but its `Index` is any `Hashable` type. So could be a `String` etc...

Also... in the cases where it is an `Int` the first index is not necessarily `0`. Array Slices for instance would not necessarily have `0` as the first index.

To get the first index of a collection you can use `self.startIndex`.

However, in the case of your logic I think what you need is...

```
someCollection.isEmpty
```

Which already exists on `Collection` and does the same as your function. Just stick a `!` on the front of it to negate the boolean.

Comment: What is relationship between Sequence and Collection, is Collection superior to Sequence? I want to know what if I use Sequence instead Collection.

Comment: Collection inherits from Sequence and Sequence doesn’t have indices. If you really want to learn about the two then read the documentation, it’s quite informative.